# Stack over flow stack graph?

Tags: discussion, statistics

What is the most popular language on the last 100 stackoverflow's questions ?
This page provide you a visualization of stackoverflow's last questions sort by the 10 most popular tags.
http://www.visualsedimentation.org/examples/stackoverflow/

If you enjoy it send us feedback on twitter @sediviz !

Comment: I get a static png image.

Comment: @11684 That's what it is..

Comment: Well, that's not an app, right? But it _is_ listed as such. @schoolboy

Comment: sorry there is a error in the url, here it is : http://www.visualsedimentation.org/examples/stackoverflow/